# What are the icons contained in the Windows 7 shell32.dll

Tags: windows-7, shell, icons, libraries, dll

I wanted to change the icon used for a Custom Library I've created in Windows 7. I found a great article [How to Customize the Library Icons in Windows 7](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/how-to-customize-library-icons-windows-7/) which describes exactly how to do that. However, the article uses `shell32.dll` and a icon location to do so. I have found an image map detailing the icons location in [shell32.dll in Windows XP](http://www.glennslayden.com/code/win32/shell32-dll-icons) but was wondering if anyone knew of something similar for Windows 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just made the map for you - here you go:

[image]

Comment: Awesome thanks! Out of curiosity what tool did you use to do so?

Comment: Axialis IconWorkshop ;) http://www.axialis.com/iconworkshop/